# Go webasm calling dat.gui external JavaScript library panic: JavaScript error: this.onResize is not a function

Tags: go, webassembly, dat.gui

I am trying to integrate the dat.gui.js library into some Go code that will be compiled to webasm.

The error I get upon visiting the page is

```
panic: JavaScript error: this.onResize is not a function wasm_exec.js:47:14
<empty string> wasm_exec.js:47:14
goroutine 1 [running]: wasm_exec.js:47:14
syscall/js.Value.Call(0x7ff800010000000d, 0x41a038, 0x33ac7, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x42c058, 0x0) wasm_exec.js:47:14
    /usr/local/go/src/syscall/js/js.go:400 +0x34 wasm_exec.js:47:14
main.main() wasm_exec.js:47:14
    /home/.../minExample.go:9 +0x3 wasm_exec.js:47:14
exit code: 2
```

I think I am misunderstanding something about how webasm works and don't understand why this causes errors and how to mitigate this issue. A minimal example of the error can be seen from

`main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall/js"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5) // Just in case the issue is with the library needing time to load in.
    gui := js.Global().Get("dat").Call("GUI").New()
    fmt.Println(gui)
}
```

`index.html`

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.7/dat.gui.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="../wasm_exec.js"></script>
    <script>
      const go = new Go();
      WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("o.wasm"), go.importObject).then((result) => {
      go.run(result.instance);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body></body>
</html>
```

and running the following command

```
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o o.wasm main.go
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to change this line

```golang
    gui := js.Global().Get("dat").Call("GUI").New()
```

to this line

```golang
    gui := js.Global().Get("dat").Get("GUI").New()
```

Found this through this related question [JS Library dat.gui not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568797/js-library-dat-gui-not-working?rq=1)